# Can Pulumi use private endpoints when updating a resource?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, pulumi, pulumi-azure

I have an Azure App Config with a private endpoint and disabled networking (only private endpoints can be used).

During the pipeline, I use Pulumi to set key/values to the above App Config which is submitting requests from a machine that is in the vnet of the App Config. This fails because networking is disabled as logs show pulumi using public REST APIs to add key/value. Is there a way for Pulumi to query and use private endpoints instead ?

PS/ when I use "az" CLI from the machine where pulumi runs, it works fine.